# Appending elements with data attributes with jQuery for use with skrollr

Tags: jquery, skrollr

I have read a question with sort of the same problem, but calling `skrollr.init` doesn't help. Skrollr doesn't animate the element appended by jQuery.

I have this jQuery in my header:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#intro').append('<div id="showcaseLaptop" class="anim fixed" data-0="right:0;" data-1500="right:-100%;"><img src="http://i58.tinypic.com/152kdmo.png" class="showcaseit" alt="Almod Web Design - Design for every device." /></div>');});
```

And I have this at the bottom of my `<body>` tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/s/skrollr.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var s = skrollr.init();
    </script>
```

I've tried calling `skrollr.init` from inside `$(document).ready` but that didn't work either.

What am I missing?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready();
```

fires after the DOM has completely build up, so the code in your head will execute after the code at the bottom of your code and therefore skrollr will not find any mathing tags/attributes.

Why not writing all of the code in a `$(document).ready()` block, no matter where it is notated?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Baster! But putting all of skrollr script inside $(document).ready() would wreck skrollr right?